# Calendar Generated error

Tags: php, calendar

I am trying to print a calendar which looking like this one:
[image: calendar]

Basically: One month per line looped for 12 months

seems it is an error that I can't find in

```
echo date( 'Y-n', $year_month )__( date('F', $year_month ), 'trav' ) . date(' Y', $year_month );
```

Can't manage to do it... There are my codes, I am struggling big time... Help !

```js
html += "<table><thead>";
  
  for ( $i = 0; $i<12; $i++ ) {
   html += "</tr>";
   
   $year_month = mktime( 0, 0, 0, date("m") + $i, 1, date("Y") );
   echo date( 'Y-n', $year_month )__( date('F', $year_month ), 'trav' ) . date(' Y', $year_month );
   
   for ( i= 0; i < 31; i++) {
    html += "<td>";
   }
   
   html += "</tr>";
  }
  
html += "</thead><tbody>";
```

Comment: This code is not in Java, it is in PHP.

Comment: Best practice tip:  you should never have to construct html/javascript from java/PHP.  Have a static html/javascript file ready to work with the proper parameters and simply put input hidden elements as a means to provide these parameters.